# How to implement unique key constraints in CouchDB

Tags: node.js, nosql, couchdb, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I use CouchDB and I would like all my users to have unique emails. I would expect that the database return a status 400 (bad request) when I try to duplicate an email.

But since there is no way to define constraints in CouchDB, I should implement it myself, my question is:

### In which layer of my application should this rule stand?

**(1) Domain objects layer**
I don't really know how to implement it in this layer

**(2) Interactor layer**
This constraint could be implemented in interactors here since there is the place where business rules stand. But if there is multiple rules for single document it could add unnecessary complexity...

```
function createUser(userData)  {
  let email = userData.email;
  let exist = await userDB.userExist(email);

  if(exist) {
    // return status 400
  } else {
    // create user
  }    
}
```

**(3) Database gateway layer**
The constraint can also be implemented in the database gateway layer. Usually we'll have a gateway for each specific entity. But does that means that external services adapters contains a bit of business logic?

```
class userDB()  {
  constructor(opts) {
    this.db = opts.db.connect();
  }

  async userExist(email) {
    return await this.db.fetchByView('email', email);
  }

  async create(email) {
    let exist = await this.userExist(data.email);
    if(exist) {
      // throw error
    } else {
      // create the user
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use [valide_doc_update](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/validation.html) in CouchDB. This function is called whenever a document is created/updated. By adding those validations in CouchDB or a facade on top of CouchDB, this let you easily maintain your business rules accross multiple platforms.

Comment: @AlexisCôté `valide_doc_update` can't enforce the Unique email address constraint in a concurrent safe way.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it :)

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Having the email as an _id is the safest thing that  you can have. As you create a user with an already existing email, you'll have a conflict error if no _rev is passed. Even tho, if you have some sort of replications, this won't be concurrent safe. 

Another solution could be to have another API on top of your database only to create users. You could have a queue that creates a user and validate their email.

Comment: I give simple example, but in real world my app require unique email as well as username and probably other fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Unique email address` is a very old DDD topic. It relates to the [set validation](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/08/12/eventual-consistency-and-set-validation/).
The simplest (and from my point of view is also the best) is to place a constraint at the database level.

From what I know, the only whay to create an unique constraint in CouchDB is to use the `_id` field so you can use [this solution](https://kfalck.net/2009/06/29/enforcing-unique-usernames-on-couchdb/). This idea is to put the email in the `_id` field.

> let exist = await this.userExist(data.email);
>
> if(exist) { // throw
>   error } else { // create the user }

This method is not safe for concurrent updates. Two users can be created at the same time. Imagine that for both the requests the `this.userExist(data.email)` is returning false.

Comment: I think I should keep the default '_id'  (uuid) key created by Couchdb, because I want to handle relationship with that _id, and if the user want to change his email address it could be an issue. But I would definitely handle the constraints in the database layer. thx

Comment: @SimonBruneaud Another solution is to create a collection only for email addresses to users allocations and there to set the `_id` to the `email address`. In other words, you would have an `EmailAddressToUserAllocation` aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a CouchDB expert but from pure Clean Architecture perspective ensuring unique email addresses is a business rule which should be implemented in an interactor.

With this approach ur business rule would remain intact even if u would once decide to replace the detail CouchDB with some other detail - another storage system.